# Mysql two different dividend algorithm base on date

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

I have below query to show records of dividend calculation once per-three month, means if someone invest 1000, base on 1.5 bonus per-month, every three month he get extra 45.

```
SELECT 
        accId, 
        name, 
        invest_date, 
        invest_amount, 
        tenure, 
        ((amount * 4.5)/100) as bonus 
FROM `account` 
WHERE `tenure` = '3' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(invest_date, '%Y%m') <> DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')
AND (MOD(MONTH(invest_date), 3) = MOD(MONTH(CURRENT_DATE), 3));//exclude current month
```

Here is the output result, for those record's month of `invest_date` is eligible up-to-today's month is able to get the bonus.

[image]

Start from July onward, the dividend will change to **1.25** monthly, assume current month is July, for those who entitled to get bonus will become 1.25; where those before July still remain rate 1.5, means if someone invested 1000 on April'18, he will get rate 1.5 for May/June, 1.25 for July, so the amount sum for three month is 102.50, and so on.

is this possible a add-on to the current query?